# How to update data in accdb from viewdatagrid with .update in vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to update a table in .accdb file from a viewdatagrid in visual studio. I have done the connection with the database and I show the data in the datagrid, but when I change some value there I cant update in DB, I have tried with dataadapter and dataset. I have the following code with dataadapter:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Frm_PAC
   Dim filter As String = ""
   Dim SQL As String = "Select * from PAC WHERE Año=" + A_T.ToString
   Private CNX As New OleDbConnection(Cnxstr)
   Dim table_PAC As DataTable
   Private DA As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, CNX)
   Private BU As New OleDbCommandBuilder
   Private tb_PAC As New DataTable
   Dim changes As DataSet

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Me.Text = Me.Text + " " + A_T.ToString

       Load_PAC_Data()

   End Sub

   Private Sub Frm_PAC_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
       On Error Resume Next
       PRINCIPAL.Show()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Load_PAC_Data()

       Try

           Me.DA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
           Me.DA.Fill(Me.tb_PAC)
           Me.T_PAC.DataSource = tb_PAC
           Me.T_PAC.AutoResizeColumn(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

       Catch ex As Exception
           Traze("Fallo al cargar PAC", ex.Message)
       End Try

   End Sub
   Private Sub Save_PAC_Data()
       Try
           Me.DA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
           If Me.tb_PAC.GetChanges() IsNot Nothing Then
               DA.Update(Me.tb_PAC)
               MessageBox.Show("OK!")
           End If

       Catch ex As Exception
           Traze("Fallo al Guardar cambios PAC", ex.Message)
       End Try
   End Sub
   Private Sub B_G_PAC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_G_PAC.Click
       Try
           Save_PAC_Data()

       Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show("NO OK!")
       End Try
   End Sub
End class
```

But when I do the update the following exception appears:

[image: 1]

(sorry, the error is in spanish :Update requires UpdateCommand to be valid when calling the DataRow collection with modified rows.)

Then I tried to do it with dataset, but neither works:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Public Class Frm_PAC
    Dim filter As String = ""
    Dim SQL As String = "Select * from PAC WHERE Año=" + A_T.ToString
    Private CNX As New OleDbConnection(Cnxstr)
    Dim table_PAC As DataTable
    Private DA As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, CNX)
    Private BU As New OleDbCommandBuilder
    Private tb_PAC As New DataTable
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim DS As New DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Text = Me.Text + " " + A_T.ToString

        Load_PAC_Data()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm_PAC_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        On Error Resume Next
        PRINCIPAL.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Load_PAC_Data()

        Try

            Me.DA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
            DA.Fill(DS)
            T_PAC.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
            T_PAC.AutoResizeColumn(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Traze("Fallo al cargar PAC", ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Sub Save_PAC_Data()
        Try
            BU = New OleDbCommandBuilder(DA)
            changes = DS.GetChanges
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                DA.Update(DS.Tables(0))
                MessageBox.Show("OK!")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Traze("Fallo al Guardar cambios PAC", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub B_G_PAC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_G_PAC.Click
        Try
            Save_PAC_Data()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("NO OK!")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error in this case is:

> {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(((? = 1 AND Id IS NULL) OR (Id = ?)) AND (Municipio = ?) AND (Poligono = ?) AND (Parcela = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND Area Cultivable IS NULL) OR (Area Cultivable = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Area Total IS NULL) OR (Area Total = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Cultivo IS NULL) OR '."} System.Exception {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException}

I don't know how solve it

Comment: This line is very, VERY bad: `Dim SQL As String = "Select * from PAC WHERE Año=" + A_T.ToString`. **NEVER** use string concatenation like that to build your SQL.

Comment: On which lines do the errors occur?

Comment: Hello, @djv just in the update `DA.Update(DS.Tables(0))`. In both cases.

Comment: Ok @JoelCoehoorn, i will try to not do again

Comment: When you get ‘Syntax error’ exception, what‘s the value of 'SQL'